# Firefox gives irregular initialization error when trying to use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, firefox, initialization

Firefox gives error "NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED" when trying to use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
.then ...
.error ...
```

which is executed inside

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
...
});
```

gives irregular error

```
[Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: my.js :: setRecorder :: line 503"  data: no]
```

in about 50% of cases on Firefox 79.0 (64-bit)

Works fine on Chrome.

Any ideas?

**Update:** The problem was in the code inside "then"
with the canvas initialization.

Comment: can you share snapshot?

Comment: it is just error field of: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).catch(function (error)

Comment: Perfect. Can you share /dev/bd.js code from line 500 to 510?

Comment: canvasStream = new MediaStream([canvas.captureStream(framePerSecond).getTracks()[0],audioTrack]);
 var options = { mimeType: "video/webm" };
// var options = { mimeType: "video/mp4" };
 mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream,options);
 mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = dataEventRec;
 mediaRecorder.onstop = stopEventRec;
 mediaRecorder.onstart = event => {
  paused = 0;

Comment: It is possible that it is complaining about Canvas actually not about microphone...

Comment: good to know you are good. it would be so great if you can share those line of code for learning purpose.

Comment: It is in my answer below

Answer (score 3):

So turns out that was actually Canvas indeed.
Added

```
canvas.getContext('2d');
```

before

```
    canvasStream = new MediaStream([canvas.captureStream(framePerSecond).getTracks()[0],audioTrack]);
```

seems to work now!